# how to read xml file with many nodes with javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, nodes

i have an RegistrationResponseMessages.xml:

```
<messages>
  <error>
    <code id="501">Couldn't retrieve the HTML document because of server-configuration problems.</code>
    <code id="502">Server busy, site may have moved ,or you lost your dial-up Internet connection.</code>
  </error>
  <success></success>
</messages>
```

trying to read contents of code id 501 and 502 with javascript, but it not works.

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else {// code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "RegistrationResponseMessages.xml", false);
        xmlhttp.send();
        xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;

        document.getElementById("errorCode403").innerHTML = getElementsByTagName(501)[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
```

displaying it here:

```
<label id="errorCode403" style="font-weight: 600; color: red;">give some error</label>
```

what is my problem?

Comment: getting sometimes error: getElementsByTagName is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's ajax, you have to wait for the data to be returned, then you have to access it the right way:

```js
var xmlhttp;

if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else {
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

xmlhttp.onload = function() {
    var xmlDoc = this.responseXML,
        value  = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('501')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    document.getElementById("errorCode403").innerHTML = value;
}

xmlhttp.open("GET", "RegistrationResponseMessages.xml", false);
xmlhttp.send();
```

Not sure about the traversal in the XML, as `501` sounds like a strange tagName ?

**EDIT:**

to get a list of the ID's you do this inside the onload handler:

```
xmlhttp.onload = function() {
    var xmlDoc = this.responseXML,

    var codes = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('code');
    var array = [];

    for (var i=0; i<codes.length; i++) {  
        array.push( codes[i].id );
    }

    console.log(array);
}
```

Comment: No, your code is ajax, that is what XMLHttpRequest is, **A** synchronous **J** avascript **A** nd **X** ML

Comment: do i need for this peace code something else to import for AJAX works on my page? i have a simple html with javascript inside

Comment: No, you do not have to import anything, it's exactly like your code but with ann onload handler for when the call has completed ?